# blur event doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an asp.net mvc page. I have a textbox which when a value is entered, and went off of the box should execute a javascript function which will roundup the value in the textbox. This works fine in Chrome and IE but not in FireFox.

The following is the code. setAmount() is the javascript function which is supposed to be executed.

```
<div class="amount-other-input">
    <div class="bold-label" style="margin-right:5px;">£</div>
    <input id="amountOther" type="number" name="other" onblur="setAmount(this)" class="numbersOnly" maxlength="4">
</div>
```

I tried in adding a timer as suggested in another stackoverflow answer as shown below, but didin't work:

```
document.getElementById('amountOther').addEventListener("blur", function() {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            setAmount(element);
        }, 1);
    }, true);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `onblur` in your HTML and `addEventListener` in your code. Use just the latter, and put your script at the foot of your page.

Comment: That code does work and I am using firefox

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have resolved it as follows:

1. By adding an onchange event
2. Calling a method to focus for onchange

   function setFocus(sender){
       $(sender).focus();
   };

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Hobo Sapiens, don't add the blur event on both the html and event listener. Just call the function directly on the `onblur` event from the html.

Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/pyjtL456/2/

Also, what version of firefox are you checking this on?

Comment: I am running FireFox 33.0. The fiddle you have provided displays the alert message. However my code still doesn't work.  After making change to the number in the textbox, then if I click in the textbox so that the cursor is inside, then if I click outside, it works. So, I tried to setfocus by code using $(sender).focus(); still doesn't work . When I put the alert in my function it is called only when I click in the textbox!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the problem. I would suggest you adopt this approach. 
Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="amount-other-input">
    <div class="bold-label" style="margin-right:5px;">£</div>
    <input id="amountOther" type="number" name="other" onblur="setAmount(this)" class="numbersOnly" maxlength="4" />
    <input id="amountOther2" type="number" name="other" class="numbersOnly" maxlength="4" />
</div>

Javascript Snippet:
<script>

    //When using the onblur property with setAmount as the value
    function setAmount(element) {
        console.log(element.value);
    }

    //When adding the blur event dynamically    
    var amountElement = document.getElementById('amountOther2');
    amountElement.addEventListener('blur', function(){
            setTimeout(setAmount(this), 1);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

£
    
    




    //When using the onblur property with setAmount as the value
    function setAmount(element) {
        console.log(element.value);
    }

    //When adding the blur event dynamically    
    var amountElement = document.getElementById('amountOther2');
    amountElement.addEventListener('blur', function(){
            setTimeout(setAmount(this), 1);
    });